# Notes linking to one another in evernote?

Tags: hyperlink, evernote

In Evernote, I want to be able to link notes to one another.

For example, I want to be able to write, "As already mentioned in ***this note***, the nature of human brain..." with "***this note***" containing a link to another note in my own evernote account.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. This is one of the ways to achieve it (for Windows version):

1. In the note list, right-click the note you want to link to and select "Copy Note Link".
2. In your note select the text that you want to act as a link ("this note" in your example).
3. Right-click on the selected text and choose Hyperlink->Add (or press Ctrl-K).
4. In the Add Link dialog, paste the link you've copied in step 1.